# tcpdump: can't create rx ring on packet socket: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: networking, tcpdump, packets

I've been using tcpdump without any issues before this error popped up. I use the following two commands with variations as soon as my server is attacked so the packets automatically get dumped if the packet rate is high.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -p -nn -s0 -c 2000 -w $dumpdir/dump.`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`.cap
tcpdump -nn -s0 -c 2000 -w $dumpdir/dump.`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`.cap
```

The following error shows up in console as soon as I'm under attack:

```
tcpdump: can't create rx ring on packet socket: Cannot allocate memory
```

Using the command manually works so my guess is that something gets overloaded in the event of an attack. Here is my RAM usage though:

```
root@x:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2004       1255        749          0          1         29
-/+ buffers/cache:       1225        779
Swap:         2047       1095        952
```

And currently, it is much lower than it used to be when the command worked.

So anyone with an answer to this?

Comment: Anyone got any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by system getting out of enough memory. I noticed it worked when a high amount of RAM was present.